# Is there any alternate way to access objects from Amazon S3?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, url, amazon-s3

I have a file in Amazon S3. I have set it to public access. The URL to access objects is https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/*******/index.html
Can I change the path so that it looks like https://www.random_domain_name.com/index.html?

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: How can I change the default format of S3 objects so that it would seems like www.random_domain_name.com/object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a CloudFront distribution which its origin refers to your S3 bucket. 
Then you will need to create a record on Route53 (or your own DNS service) like follows:

- Name: static.example.com
- Type: CNAME
- Alias: Yes
- Alias Target: Your CloudFront distribution

Answer (score 0):

Configure the S3 bucket for public access and pick the "Use this bucket to host a website" option in the configuration.

Further reading: [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)
 in the S3 documentation.

Comment: I tried as you said. I used redirect request option and then entered my domain name along with protocol used.  But now when I click on my link it gets redirected to the domain name and path specified but throws error 'Not Found'